# Distorted leaves, white spots, and welts on basil

Tags: pests, basil

I'm currently gearing up to start some basil seeds and doing an inventory of my closet greenhouse. One of my basil plants has recently been absolutely wrecked by... Something, or multiple things, and I'm curious what happened and if there's anything I ought to do with the greenhouse and the soil before planting.

So, any insight into what happened here would be appreciated! I've got a basil seedling I was gifted mid winter and a few citrus plants I'd like to keep safe from whatever this is.

Symptoms:
Severely distorted leaf growth - horizontal curling
Light spots with dark centers
Welts on some leaf tops
Dull white spots throughout leaf - don't follow any particular trail

[image: Pictures here: http://imgur.com/gallery/xSgI8K8]

[image: Basil]